# How to disable login in iframe which is hosted in same domain?

Tags: plugins, php, iframe

I want to disable auto login on iframe which is embeded in wordpress dashboard page. I have page(/booking) which uses login info to prefill customer data. I want to embed that page in iframe in wp-admin dasboard without being logged in. Is it possible.

Comment: please explain more i didn't get it.

Comment: In Wordpress i have logged in on wp-admin, i have another page /booking where if user is logged in some information is prefilled. I have created a iframe in wp-admin as a widget and i want to have /booking page as non-loggedin user(Example like incognito mode iframe) Is it possible to logout one page in wordpress.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hi, Please refer to this link. For more clarification.
https://staging2.pennsyline.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/03/New-Project.png